# Sorting elements in a list of lists

Tags: python, list

Hey I have a list that goes like:

```
List = [[[1,2],[4,5,3]],[[5,2],[3,4,7]],...]
```

and I want to sort the elements of each sublist, that the output looks like:

```
List = [[[2,1],[5,4,3]],[[5,2],[7,4,3]],...]
```

What I have already tried is creating a loop like this.

```
for i in List:
    for u in [i]:
        List[u].sort(reverse = True)
        print(List)
```

but it didnt worked. In other Blogposts I just found ways how to sort the lists, but not the elements in them.
Thanks for your help

Comment: You seem to have a mismatch of square brackets, so it’s not clear whether you’ve a list of list, or list of list of list. Also, please define “didn’t work”. What happened? Did your computer started shaking and smoke started coming out?

Comment: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Comment: I would look into the syntax of `for loops`. The bracket notation is used for doing something at a specific index in a list, and it seems like you use it arbitrarily. For example, you would do `List[u]` to access a specific item in `List`.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar The square brackets are not mismatched, it is a lists of lists of lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, just a few things wrong:

`for u in [i]:` Do not wrap `i` in brackets. You are just creating a new list with `i` as its only element, and looping over that which is not what you want.

Second:

`List[u].sort(reverse = True)` You do not need to do `List[u]`, rather just `u`, because inside of this loop, `u` is equal to the sublist that you want to sort

Also a side note, variables should be lowercase

```
myList = [[[1,2],[4,5,3]],[[5,2],[3,4,7]]]
for i in myList: 
    for u in i: 
        u.sort(reverse=True) 
print(myList)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use a list comprehension, to easily retrieve the values, iterate over each sublist and sort the subsublist

```
values = [[[1, 2], [4, 5, 3]], [[5, 2], [3, 4, 7]]]
values = [[sorted(subsub, reverse=True) for subsub in sub] for sub in values]
print(values) # [[[2, 1], [5, 4, 3]], [[5, 2], [7, 4, 3]]]
```

Or with loops, you can just access the inner lists with the second loop and inline sort them

```
for sub in values:
    for subsub in sub:
        subsub.sort(reverse=True)
```

---

*Note:* use meaningful names to your variables

Answer (score 1):

You are close with your approach although in your second loop you’re enclosing `i` in a list which won’t loop through each sub list and you only need to sort `u` as you’re not going to slice a list with a list.

```
for i in List:
    for u in i:
        u.sort(reverse = True)

print(List)
```

Result:

```
[[[2, 1], [5, 4, 3]], [[5, 2], [7, 4, 3]]]
```

**PS** If there could be only one layer of nesting then I'd suggest using `isinstance` to check before looping through and error-ing out due to attempting to sort an `int`

```
for i in List:
    if isinstance(i[0], list):
        for u in i:
            u.sort(reverse = True)
    else:
        i.sort(reverse = True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using `list comprehension` (one liner):

```
li = [[[1,2],[4,5,3]],[[5,2],[3,4,7]]]

li = [[sorted(i, reverse=True) for i in j] for j in li]

print(li)
```

Output:

```
[[[2, 1], [5, 4, 3]], [[5, 2], [7, 4, 3]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
for i in List:
    for u in i:
        u.sort(reverse = True)
```

Comment: It is, but it may be good to explain why OP's code did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pandas to sort your data.

```
import pandas as pd

ist = [[[1,2],[4,5,3]],[[5,2],[3,4,7]]]
df = pd.DataFrame(ist)
```

I named the columns to read the columns easier.

```
df.columns = ['a', 'b']
```

Now we can sort the elements of the lists in each,

```
df['a'] = df.a.apply(lambda x: sorted(x,reverse=True))
df['b'] = df.b.apply(lambda x: sorted(x,reverse=True))
```

which yields,

```
print(df.head())

    a          b
0  [2, 1]  [5, 4, 3]
1  [5, 2]  [7, 4, 3]
```